# qemu is returning no output after file is fed

Tags: assembly, x86-64, osdev

I am very new to making operating systems so this question is pretty dumb, the following code gives me no output on Qemu(x86_64)

```
[org 0x7c00]
section .text:
    mov ah,0x0e
    mov bx,mystr
    jmp start
    
    start:
        mov al,[bx]
        cmp al, 0
        je exit
        int 0x10
        inc bx
        jmp start
    
    exit:
        jmp $
        times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
        db 0x55,0xaa

section .data:
    mystr:
        db "Hi there I is pc",0
```

However, it does give the message "Booting from hard disk...". I am running this code using nasm on windows 10.

I expected to get:

```
Hi there I is pc
```

Comment: You put your string into the next sector which isn't loaded. Also you did not initialize `ds` segment register.